# Partial Searching of Strings

Tags: java

I have a requirement to convert a longName to a shortName based on a list of longNames and corresponding shortNames that are stored in a DB Table.  The table has a approx. 500 entries and not expected to grow.

Example: I receive a request with the `longName` value set to something like: `Royal Bank of Scotland Euro` so the `shortName` value output look something like: `RBOS €` based on its value from the DB.

I can load the DB entries of LongNames and shortNames into a Map and key the Map on the `longName` value and check if each value 
in the string on the request exists as a key in the Map but this seems like a inefficient way to search for the corresponding 
`shortName`. In the above example i would need to read the Map 4 times before finding a match of `RBOS` as I don't know how many values in the String would make up each Key to read the Map.

I want to know if there's a more efficient approach to this problem?

Comment: Could you please clarify the "4 times"? I'd only see one query `map.get("Royal Bank of Scotland Euro")` immediately giving `"RBOS"`. So probably I'm misunderstanding your real problem.

Comment: I don't know how many values in the String would make up each Key to read the Map so i would need to check the Map for `Royal` first then `Royal Bank` etc.. My problem is the value that comes in the on request could contain one or many keys so in the above scenario the incoming request value contains 2 keys `Royal Bank of Scotland` and `Euro`

Comment: IMHO it does not matter how often you have to query the map. The overall complexity is still O(n) (n being the number of words in the sentence). That does not sound too bad. In fact, I don't think you will get any better than this.

Comment: A different and probably more severe problem: Boundaries could be ambiguous. E.g. if your sentence is "A B C", you could split it into "A B" and "C", or "A" and "B C", and maybe both are possible, and you have to decide which it is, or only one variant is possible, requiring backtracking after matching the first few possible segments.

Answer (score 0):

Make a stored procedure (which nobody actually likes).

Parsing "Royal Bank of Scotland Euro" goes as:

Start with the longest sequence

1. "Royal Bank of Scotland Euro" fails
2. "Royal Bank of Scotland" succeeds - "RBOS"

   1. Recurse with "Euro" succeeds - "€"
   2. Store "Royal Bank of Scotland Euro" -> "RBOS €" maybe with an extra boolean column value DERIVED

A variant case:

1. "Royal Bank of Scotland Euro" fails
2. "Royal Bank of Scotland" assume it fails
3. "Royal Bank of" assume it succeeds "RBO

   1. Recurse with "Scotland Euro" -> "S Euro" (assuming Euro fails)
   2. Store "Royal Bank of Scotland Euro" -> "RBO S Euro" maybe with an extra boolean column value DERIVED 1

Eventually every access will be yield a result.

I have seen sufficient cases where the implementation choice went to a java parsing solution, with perhaps some caching. That I do not find such a bad solution either.